# how to use ng2-bootstrap for angular2 in visual studio code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, ng2-bootstrap

Is there any set of steps to be able to use ng2 bootstrap in an Angular2 application using VS CODE IDE. Please share the same. Shall be thankful. I have installed the ng2-bootstrap module using following command:

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap --save
```

what to be done after this step? Do we need moment.js to be able to use ng2-bootstrap?

Comment: There are some pretty decent instructions [on the GitHub page](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) of the ng2-bootstrap project. Your IDE has little to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ran `npm install --save ng2-bootstrap`, you need follow these steps-

In Systemjs.config.js, configure ng2-bootstrap like this-

```
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
```

In index.html add these

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In your component you can use like this-

```
import {AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

Sample implementation:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <alert type="info">ng2-bootstrap hello world!</alert>
      <pre>Selected date is: <em *ngIf="dt">{{ getDate() | date:'fullDate'}}</em></pre>
      <h4>Inline</h4>
      <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
      </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public dt:Date = new Date();
  private minDate:Date = null;
  private events:Array<any>;
  private tomorrow:Date;
  private afterTomorrow:Date;
  private formats:Array<string> = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'shortDate'];
  private format = this.formats[0];
  private dateOptions:any = {
    formatYear: 'YY',
    startingDay: 1
  };
  private opened:boolean = false;

  public getDate():number {
    return this.dt && this.dt.getTime() || new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

And in app.module.ts import Ng2BootstrapModule like this-

```
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

....
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2BootstrapModule
  ],
....
```

Also, you can refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2lDiJaezvCOcSyd2dd2Q?p=preview)